# Unable to replace the column having blank value with NULL while creating the table script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a table in which all the column should automatically replace the blank value i.e '' with NULL.

Here is my Table creation script

```
create table #test
(
firstname varchar(50),
lastname varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #test select ' ', ' '
```

While I use the insert script with the blank values, I want to replace it with NULL values while inserting in the table.

Is there any idea to implement this logic while creating the table script itself? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use stored procedure

Comment: use default NULL if you find blanks

Comment: have you tried using triggers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The here is the trigger code.

```
create table test (
firstname varchar(50)   ,
lastname varchar(50));

INSERT INTO test select ' ', ' '

CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateDesc
ON test 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO test (firstname, lastname)
    SELECT case when firstname = ' ' then null else firstname end, case when lastname = ' ' then null else lastname end FROM inserted
END 

select * from test
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are looking for the `default` keyword:

```
create table #test (
    firstname varchar(50) not null default '',
    lastname varchar(50) not null default ''
);
```

The `not null` is optional.  So, if you don't provide a value (or if you use the `default` keyword in the insert), then you'll get the default value.

Comment: I dont think so that while using the
INSERT INTO #test select '', ''
will insert the value NULL in the firstname and lastname using the above statement.